# system.security.cryptography.protecteddata ,this error I'm getting in code build time. I'm was added Nuget package related to cryptography

Tags: c#, api

> Error MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\surendra.reddy.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.protecteddata\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.   PublishReportNotification   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   4679

Comment: Usually this is because the program is running while you're trying to build it

Comment: The file is in use, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was because the name of the destination of the project was too long. If you have something like D:\someFolder\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder\Folder\Folder\etc\myApp, Visual Studio would throw this error. There is a restriction on the destination length.

Answer (score 0):

This Error arrives because of the exceeded count of the retry method.
`MSBuild` has certain number of limit to copy the file.
If that limit has exceeded, this error will occur.

This will also occur when the destination file is in use by another program.

For example: If you try to move the program from one to another destination when running, It will give `MSB3027`
The detailed problem will be [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb3027?view=vs-2022).

Comment: what is the solution to fix this error

Comment: If you have to use the program, then you have to stop one instance of the program that is running. After stopping the instance you can run the another instance of the same program.